# LotusScript - Get all values of Document

Tags: lotusscript, lotus

Is there a way to print all the possible contents of an item for `GetItemValue`?

For example, I know `DeliveredDate` and `From` are contents, but I would like to see all the possibilities, but I cannot find a reference for this.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something like NotesDocument.items ?

Comment: Or do you mean the choices for the field in the form design?

Comment: Thanks umeli, but if I look at t NotesDocument.items, how can I get the field name?

Comment: The item.name property is the name of the field.

Comment: Thanks for the insight

Comment: There's something like the Notes Designer Help with all these kind of nice infos in it...